# C# Как заставить метод подождать выполнения таймера (тиканья)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Пишу простенькое приложение, застопорился на вот этом моменте, как заставить метод StartExercises подождать пока выполниться таймер ("протикает" от значения Mid до 0) ? Подозреваю что нужно использовать потоки, но не хочу пока в эту тему влазить) Если других вариантов нету, то как реализовать с потоками?

```
protected void StartExercises(List<Exercise> list)
    {
        foreach (var ex in list)
        {
            Sec = ex.Duration;
            Timer1.Enabled = true;
            LabelName.Text += ex.Name; ;
        }
    }


    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Sec > 0)
        {
            Sec -= 1;
            LabelTimer.Text = Sec.ToString();
        }
        else if (Sec <= 0)
        {
            Timer1.Enabled = false;
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer { SoundLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/EndSound.WAV") };
            sp.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что мешает подписаться на событие таймера? В обработчике события закладываете необходимую логику и все.

Comment: Именно для таких случаев существуют *события* (event)

Comment: Точно ASP.NET? Таймер будет тикать на сервере, не в браузере. И саундплеер тоже на сервере будет работать.

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, ломаю голову целый день, не могу придумать каким образом реализовать все через события, подскажите на примере, спасибо

Comment: Толсто намекаю еща раз: таймер должен тикать и звук воспроизводиться на сервере (C#) или в браузере (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем вам это понадобилось, когда вы могли бы подписаться на событие от таймера и в обработчике выполнить нужную вам логику.

Однако, если вам все таки по какие-то причинам это не подходит, то вы можете крутится в цикле while проверяя таймер и когда настанет заветная секунда сделать break, но это не совсем правильно...